# How to predict input image with cnn trained model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I have trained cnn model for MNIST digit recognition...now I want to provide my own input to my model and expecting for the correct output with label name...
I dont know how to provide input to my trained model could anyone please help me....here is my full code......

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn as model_fn_lib

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
sess = tf.Session()


def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):

  input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 28, 28, 1])


  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs= input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)


  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)


  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5],padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)

  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

  dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training= mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

  loss = None
  train_op = None

  if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=10)
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=0.001,
        optimizer="SGD")

  # Generate Predictions
  predictions = {
      "classes": tf.argmax(
          input=logits, axis=1),
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(
          logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }

  # Return a ModelFnOps object
  return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(
      mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

  # Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = learn.Estimator(
      model_fn= cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/home/kumar/Downloads/")

  # Set up logging for predictions
  # Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

  # Train the model
  mnist_classifier.fit(
      x=train_data,
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=100,
      steps=20000,
      monitors=[logging_hook])

# Configure the accuracy metric for evaluation
  metrics = {
      "accuracy":
          learn.MetricSpec(
              metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
  }

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(
      x=eval_data, y=eval_labels, metrics=metrics)
  print(eval_results)

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  saver.restore(sess, "/home/kumar/Downloads/model_simple.ckpt")
  print("model restored.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Use `predict` to feed in your data and get the predicted label.

```
mnist_classifier.fit(your_data)    # your_data should have shape = (number_of_sample, number_of_features)
```

Refer to the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator#predict).

Comment: I have changed my data but now how can I input my own data to predict the correct output label